# Using Vue, Manually cycle through slides when using v-for with a computed array to set a max height

Tags: vue.js

I have an interesting problem. I have  slider that dynamically loads components on each slide. Using a v-for and a computed function to display the proper component in the slide.

I need to get the height of the tallest slide so that I can set it on the main container so the slider won't move around. Problem is that the component doesn't exists until the next slide is triggered because it the component doesn't exist yet.

My best guess is that I need to somehow manually loop through and load each slide while gathering the height on mounted however so far I have had no luck. Thanks for any help you can give

So the ref slide never changes. Only the components inside of it But on mounted I want to load each component and get the height of the slide each time and compare it to the previous height. I only ever get the first slide height.

I tried to add in the relevant pieces and I hope I have explained my problem well enough to help

```
<template>
    <div
        ref="slide"
        class="slide card-body"
        :id="'slide-' + currentSlide"
        :key="'slide-' + currentSlide">

      <vhsLoader
        v-for="(component, c) in activeComponents"
        :id="`component-${c}`"
        :key="`component-${c}`"
        :fileNameStub="component.config.fileNameStub"
        :data="component">
      </vhsLoader>

  </div>

</template>



data: function () {
    slideHeight: null,
    currentSlide: 0,
}

mounted () {
// Attempt tot get the tallest slide, only gets me the first slide height
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (this.currentSlide = 0; this.currentSlide <= this.slideLength; this.currentSlide++) {
        let originalHeight
        let slide = this.$refs.slide
        originalHeight = slide.getBoundingClientRect().height
          if (originalHeight > this.slideHeight) {
            this.slideHeight = originalHeight
          }
         log(originalHeight)
        }
     }, 800)
}


 computed: {
    slideLength () {
      // Return total number of expected slides
      return this.$props.cData.body.length
    },
    activeComponents () {
        return this.data.body[this.currentSlide]
    }
 }
```

// THIS.DATA. looks something like this
// Basically each array item in the body can have x amount of objects, each object contains a config and body that are the component options

```
{
    "config": {
        "fileNameStub": "quiz",
        "version": "1"
     },
    "body": {
        [
            {
                "config": {
                   "fileNameStub": "stub1",
                   // Other config options
                }
                "body": {
                  // Body content
                }
            }
        ]
        [
            {
                "config": {
                   "fileNameStub": "stub2",
                   // Other config options
                }
                "body": {
                  // Body content
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: why not watch `currentSlide` and when it changes, get the height of the slide and set it accordingly

Comment: But wouldn't I still have to wait until a user triggered next Slide? I need to get the tallest height on mounted so the user won't notice a height change. If I do on the fly I will only be getting the tallest height when a user goes to that slide

Comment: How will you know what the tallest slide is until it is rendered? How would you go about figuring that out?

Comment: Couldn't this be solved by using pure CSS? Couldn't the main container adapt to the height of the current slide automatically? So just by *not* setting a fixed height at a certain point in time?

Comment: @mynd if I understand correctly, he wants to set the height to the largest slide in order to prevent the screen from jumping.

Comment: @DerekPollard Yes that is correct. Which is why I am trying to loop through/render all the slides on mounted by increasing the currentSlide for the slideLength. Afterwards I would set the currentSlide back to 0

Comment: OK, I see. Like Derek is already pointing out, you will need to actually render the slides. Depending on how it will affect performance (complexity of the slides) you could render all slides and setting `style.visibility = "hidden" `. By doing this you are able to retrieve the height and still hide them.

Comment: Mhm, I get that. That;ts what I am attempting to do on mounted by increasing the currentSlide number. It is my thinking that it would go to slide 2 render get height > go to slide 3 render compare height > and so on. But it does not work like this. unfortunately. We cant use something like v-show because we need the components to render when there slide changes(we had some issues with component not working right with v-show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I have found a solution. On mounted each slide is looped through. During each iteration we load the component, get is height compare it and then trigger nextSlide() and repeat. We set a timeout in the function to ensure the component has loaded when it gathers it's height. When the current slide = the total slides we reset current slide back to 0 so we return to the first slide.

I also added a small loader while it is calculation heights to switching through the slide is not visible

```
<div
    ref="slide"
    class="slide card-body"
    :id="'slide-' + currentSlide"
    :key="'slide-' + currentSlide"
    :style="`height: ${slideHeight}px`">

   // Components load in here

</div>

data: function() {
return {
    currentSlide: 0,
    slideHeight: null
  }
},

async mounted () {
    this.slideHeight = await this.getHeight()
}

methods: {
    async getHeight () {
      let maxHeight = 0

      for(let item of this.data.body) {
        // Set a timeout to ensure components are loaded
        await this.timeOut(500)
        // Get the height of the slide once component is loaded into it
        let slide = this.$refs.slide
        let newHeight = slide.getBoundingClientRect().height
        // If newHeight isd greater than maxHeight maxHeight becomes newHeight
        maxHeight = newHeight > maxHeight ? newHeight : maxHeight
        // Switch the slide
        await this.nextSlide()
      }

      // if current slide equals quiz length reset it to 0 to begin the interactive
      if (this.currentSlide === this.data.body.length) {
        this.currentSlide = 0
        this.loader = false;
      }

      return maxHeight
    },

    timeOut (num) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Basic timeout function that will resolve when finished
        setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, num) 
      })
    },

    async nextSlide () {
      if (this.currentSlide < this.slideLength) {
        this.currentSlide++
      }
      return true
    },

}
```